Convergence in $L^1_\text{loc}$ of weak derivates
Let $I$ an open inteval in $\mathbb{R}$. I'm looking for an example of a sequence of functions $(u_n)$ and a function $u$ in $I$ such that $u_n$ for all $n$ and $u$ has weak derivates $u_n'$ and $u'$ and $u_n\to u$  but $u_n'\not\to u'$ both in $L_\text{loc}^1$.
I'm running out of ideas. My last attempt was consider functions
$$
 u_n = |x|^n \quad \text{and} \quad  x = 0
$$
with $I=(-1,1)$ since the derivate should be had an $n$ to diverge but doesn't work. Any idea?

What kind of convergence are you requiring? Pointwise or weak convergence?

In $L^1_\text{loc}$. i.e., for all compact $K$ in $I$, $\int_K u_n, dx \to \int_K u$.

What you are looking for is a "typewriter sequence." Let:
$$f(n)=2^{-\lfloor\log_{2}\left(n+1\right)\rfloor}$$
$$g(n)=n+1-2^{\lfloor\log_{2}\left(n+1\right)\rfloor}$$
$$h(n)=g(n)f(n)$$
Intuitively the sequence $h(n)$ is constructed by appending the finite sequences $\{k2^{-n}\}_{k=0}^{k=n-1}$ to each other so that it looks like:
$$0, 0,\frac 12, 0, \frac 14, \frac 24,\frac 34, \dots$$
Denote the bump function:
$$\varphi(x):=\begin{cases}2x & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq \frac 12\\
2-2x & \text{if } \frac 12 \leq x \leq 1\\
0 &\text{else} \end{cases}$$
Then the sequence:
$$\psi_n(x):=\varphi\left(2^{\lfloor\log_{2}\left(n+1\right)\rfloor}(x+h(n))\right)$$
Is such that $\psi_n$ looks like a triangle with base $b_n$ and height $1$, where $b_n$ is:
$$1, \frac 12,\frac 12, \frac 14,\frac 14,\frac 14,\frac 14, \dots$$
So that $\psi_n \to 0$ in $L^1$. However, $|\psi_n'|$ is the indicator function of an interval of length $b_n$ times $c_n:=\frac 2{b_n}$, and so it has uniformly positive $L^1$ norm of $2$. Take your interval to be any interval slightly larger than $[0,1]$ and you have your counterexample. Let me know if you want any more details.

Could you provide more details about the derívate of the sequence. Please
